# add button component to a 2d sprite in unity 2d for mobile

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to select sprites in unity mobile. So I think a way is add button component to sprite but when I do that, it does not work.

I did the same things for normal buttons adding script in on click function and button works. But can't do same thing in sprite.

Am i missing something?

If anyone knows another better way to select game objects in mobile please tell
for example I want upgrade a game object by clicking on it.

[image: like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I totaly understand what is your goal, but if you just want to detect if user clicked game object on mobile you can use `Input.touches`

```
void Update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
    {
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            Vector3 p = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(i).position);

            int layerMask = 1 << objectLayer;
            Ray ray = new Ray(p, Vector3.forward * distance);
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.GetRayIntersection(ray, distance, layerMask);

            if (hit.collider != null)
            {
                YourObject obj = hit.collider.GetComponent<YourObject>();
                if (obj != null)
                {
                    // player clicked on the object
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I did not test that code but it should roughly work for 2D, `objectLayer` is the index of the layer of your object and `distance` is how far should the Raycast go.

I have never done somthing like this for 3D but I guess it would be simillar.

Comment: yeah , its good, but in which part code knows that  touch overlap with gameobject? the game object is moving around

Comment: right, so I added the detection part for 2D, if your game is 3D then the Raycasting part might change a little